# Math plugin for aloha editor

Tags: math, aloha-editor

I was looking at [aloha](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/Aloha-Editor) editor as a cool lightweight editor. But I need to be able to add/edit math formulas. Is there a plugin or some other way for aloha to support math?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the special characters required by math formulas, you could include the `characterpicker` plugin. Also, the `format` plugin supports subscript and superscript, which would come in handy.

```
<script src="path/to/aloha.js"
    data-aloha-plugins="common/format, common/characterpicker"></script>
```